# Difference between Sphyraena obtusata and Sphyraena novaehollandiae

Tags: species-identification, zoology, ichthyology, marine-biology

"Striped barracuda" is the common name for both *Sphyraena obtusata* and the *Sphyraena novaehollandiae*.

Here's links to both fish species from fishesofausralia.net: [*S. novaehollandiae*](http://fishesofaustralia.net.au/home/species/2550) and [*S. obtusata*](http://fishesofaustralia.net.au/home/species/2547)

Are they the same fish just found in different parts of Australia, or are they completely different species? If they are different species, what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have looked at these species too quickly.

They are in fact *different* species.

[*Sphyraena obtusata*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obtuse_barracuda) is referred to as the obtuse barracuda, the **striped barracuda**, or various other names that your linked website ([fishesofausralia.net](http://fishesofaustralia.net.au/home/species/2547)) provides:

> Dingo Fish, Obtuse Barracuda, Pike, Sennit, Short-finned Seapike, Short-finned Sea-pike, Short-jawed Sea-pike, Striped Sea Pike, Yellowstripe Barracuda, Yellowtail, Yellowtail Barracuda, Yellowtail Sennit

[*Sphyraena novaehollandiae*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_barracuda), on the other hand, is referred to as the **Australian barracuda**, arrow barracuda, Australian sea pike, sea pike, **snook**, or shortfin barracuda.

- Even your [linked post](http://fishesofaustralia.net.au/home/species/2550) doesn't provide "striped barracuda" as a common name for this species.

**Differentiating the two species**:

Your fishesofausralia.net links demonstrate these fish are found on different sides of Australia (*S novaehollandiae* in the south and *S. obtusata* in the North of Australia.

The Wikipedia articles for these fish (linked previously in my answer) indicate that *S. obtusata* only reaches maximum lengths of 55cm, while *S novaehollandiae* can reach sizes exceeding 1 meter.

Both sources also list a number of additional color and morphological variations you can use to differentiate the two species.

Comment: @AshleyS if this adequately answers your question, please consider accepting the answer. Thanks :)